# Create related table to avoid possible empty fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

let's say i have a table named **movie_celebrity** which has the following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `movie_celebrity` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `movie_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `celebrity_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `movie_celebrity_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `character_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

so if the type of the celebrity is **writer** or **director** the fields `role` and `character_name` will be empty, only if the type is **actor** this fields will be filled.

Is this a really bad design? Or is this just slightly inefficient?
I would assume the creating a separate table for this two columns would be better.

**Edit** (including schema)

movie table:

```
CREATE TABLE `movie` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `poster` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `release_Date` date NOT NULL,
  `runtime` time NOT NULL,
  `storyline` text NOT NULL,
  `rated` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` float(2,1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0',
  `inserted` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Celebrity table:

```
CREATE TABLE `celebrity` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` date NOT NULL,
  `biography` text NOT NULL
)
```

Movie_Celebrity table:

```
CREATE TABLE `movie_celebrity` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `movie_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `celebrity_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `character_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Comment: I think it's a poor design. Cast and production are clearly separate kinds of thing - regardless of the fact that the roles maybe undertaken by the same person.

Comment: @Strawberry so do you think i should use entirely different table for production ? or just move the role and character_name into related table ? thanks.

Comment: Well, that's what I would do.

Comment: @Strawberry which one ? create a different table for role and character or entirely different table for production ?

Comment: I would have a table for movies, a little able for casts, and a table for crew. And a table of people- celebrated or otherwise

Comment: I'd probably start with movies and people. Then a table *cast* can link movies to people with the addition of a character name, or optionally a reference to a character table (so you can store recurring information about a character). And indeed a crew table that links people to job titles. That format allows you store people only once and connect them to everything they have done.

Comment: `movie_celebrity_type_id` and `role` seem redundant. Could you give an example of why they both need to be there?

Comment: @Schwern role means "leading" or "supporting"

Comment: @Ayoubk So `movie_celebrity_type_id` would indicate "actor" and `role` would make it more specific? How does a "2nd Unit Director" fit this model?

Comment: @Schwern if the celebrity is director, the role and character name fields will be empty.

Comment: @Ayoubk Can the celebrity have more than one type? For example, Alfred Hitchcock is a director, writer, actor, and producer. If you showed `celebrities` and `movie_celebrity_types`, and declared their relationships with `movie_celebrity` that would help.

Comment: @GolezTrol i have table movie and table celebrity and a table movie_celebrity link the movie with celebrity so i have a type column inside the movie_celebrity to tell if the celebrity is actor, director or writer. now if the actor is writer or director the role and character fields will be empty, now the question should i create a table for role and character to avoid a lot of empty fields ?

Comment: @Schwern yes we can have a celebrity as writer and director and even actor. See my edit. Thank you.

Comment: @Ayoubk And what table does `movie_celebrity_type_id` refer to?

Comment: @Schwern ah my mistake, it's just type: varchar (actor, director...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're trying to make a combined "cast and crew" table. Depending on what you're doing with it, it may be a good idea to combine them all in one table, or maybe it would be better to have separate "cast" and "crew". I'd say to start with a combined table and see how that goes. If it doesn't work out, you can split the table and [create a view](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-views-tutorial.aspx) for backwards compatibility.

According to the author's comments, `movie_celebrity_type_id` is for things like "writer" or "actor" or "director" while `role` is for a "leading" or "supporting". This seems odd. Many movies do not define "leading" vs "supporting" cast. And many celebrities are directories, writers, actors, and producers. Alfred Hitchcock is a good example.

Your `movie` and `celebrity` tables are fine, though I'd probably just call them `persons`. I'd design the table connecting them like so:

```
create table cast_and_crew (
    id integer primary key auto_increment,
    movie_id integer not null,
    celebrity_id integer not null,
    role text not null,
    character_name text,
    credited boolean not null default true,
    notes json not null default '{}'

    foreign key(movie_id) references movie(id),
    foreign key(celebrity_id) references celebrity(id),

    -- Include the character name for people who act in more than one role
    unique(movie_id, celebrity_id, role, character_name)
);
```

This is far more than simply a movie/celebrity join table, so I've given it a descriptive name `cast_and_crew`. Since the otherwhelming majority of entries will be actors with a `character_name`, it's fine to make that a real column. The `notes` [JSON column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) provides flexibility for any other bits of data without having to add more columns.

For example, Alfred Hitchcock's uncredited appearance in [The Birds](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056869/fullcredits)...

```
insert into cast_and_crew (movie_id, celebrity_id, role, character_name, credited)
    values(<The Birds>, <Alfred Hitchcock>, 'actor', 'Man Walking Dogs Out of Pet Shop', false);
```

`<The Birds>` and `<Alfred Hitchcock>` are their respective IDs.

Then again as producer and director.

```
insert into cast_and_crew (movie_id, celebrity_id, role)
    values(<The Birds>, <Alfred Hitchcock>, 'producer');

insert into cast_and_crew (movie_id, celebrity_id, role)
    values(<The Birds>, <Alfred Hitchcock>, 'director');
```

Whereas Peggy Robertson, assistant to Alfred Hitchcock, might take advantage of the `notes` column like so.

```
insert into cast_and_crew (movie_id, celebrity_id, role, noes)
    values(<The Birds>, <Peggy Robertson>, 'assistant', '{ "to": <Alfred Hitchcock> }');
```

The code using this table could be written to instantiate a subclass based on the role. For example, you could write a generic `CastAndCrew` class. Then the `CastAndCrew::Actor` subclass would provide a `name` method and require it be defined. `CastAndCrew::Assistant` would know to look for a `to` field in `notes`.

Another example is Ray Berwick credited as "trainer of the birds". You could put in `role = 'trainer of the birds'` but what if you want to search for all animal trainers? You could have verbatum and normalized roles, the verbatum role is "trainer of the birds" and the normalized role is "animal trainer". Depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

There could be more improvements, but they depend on knowing what you want to do with the data.